# Woocommerce REST API not returning the default category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to get all the product category from woocommerce using it's REST Api. I am using the path `https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories`. This endpoint returns all categories but the default one.

Is there any way get the default category also? I need it to fetch the products of that category. Please help me someone.

Comment: What is the default category? by default means all the products will be in uncategorized category so you want to fetch that category?

Comment: Yes, I have a default category named as Toys. I want to fetch the products of that category.

Comment: In total how many categories do you have?

Comment: Around 18 categories

Comment: Imran I have updated my answer check it once and let me know if it helps

Comment: No, I did that already but the same result :(

Answer (score 2):

You can get the products of specific category like this

```
https://yoursite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?category=categoryId
```

Where **categoryId** is the **Id** of your category you need

> Note: By Default Woocommerce API gives you the only 10 categories make
> sure you get all the categories either you can mention `per_page` or
> `page` variable in the query like this

```
https://yoursite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories?per_page=100
```

Note when using per_page you can mention value between 10 - 100

```
https://yoursite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories?page=2
```

Comment: Yes I know that but I'm not getting the categoryId of the default category

Comment: Means you are not getting the id of the category named Toys? Is it not coming in the response?

Comment: No it's not not coming in the response and that is the problem

Comment: Very strange ... BTW how did you set your default category?

Comment: On woocommerce edit category page just clicking a category make default.